# run a class file inside a web project in linux

Tags: java, linux

Lets say i have a class file `A.class` and i keep it inside some package of an already exisiting web project in deployed in glassfish server in linux. `A.class` has many dependent with many other classes in same package or other package of the same web project.
Now i `cd` into the folder and try to run `java A` it throws following exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError /path/A`.Is it because the class file coulnot find its dependencies?. Is there any way to make it run.

Error log. Here the class file i want to run is ChangeBulkPassword

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project_name/ChangeBulkPassword
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project_name.ChangeBulkPassword
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.project_name.ChangeBulkPassword. Program will exit.
```

Edit:

**I `cd` to `project_name\WEB-INF\classes` and then run `java packagename.ChangeBulkPassword`.It throws exception that i cannot find required library.Is there a way to reference those libraries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your A.class has a package name com.xxx.yyy there must be a directory tree com/xxx/yyy,you should cd to the directory where com directory exists and then run the class by type java com.xxx.yyy.A.

***EDIT:***
If there is a directory tree:
/home/me/webapps/com/project_name/ChangeBulkPassword

cd

cd webapps

java -classpath "." com.project_name.ChangeBulkPassword

Comment: @ntstha maybe your classpath does not reconginze the current directory,try my new edit commands.

Comment: hey @tianwei..actually the previous command java com.project_name.ChangeBulkPassword works..its throwing new exception. Now it cannot find library files.How can i specify lib files also??

Comment: @ntstha If your libs directory where your library files exist  has a path:/home/me/webapps/libs/,Then you can use this command to execute:java -classpath ".:/home/me/webapps/libs/*" com.project_name.ChangeBulkPassword

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49623/discussion-between-ntstha-and-tianwei)